# cutting up object in array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a Array that can contain one or more strings. This is my input:

> 51403423 0001051629      1302130622 TOMTOM101  Order 51403423-3-179178687: ontvangen
>   51403423 0001051629      1302130644 TOMTOM241  Order 51403423-3-179178687: gestart
>   51403423 0001051629      1302130645 TOMTOM241  Order 51403423-3-179178687: geschatte aankomst 7:33, 57 km op bes
>   51403423 0001051629      1302130937 TOMTOM241  Order 51403423-3-179178687: gestart
>   51403423 0001051629      1302130951 TOMTOM249  Order 51403423-3-179178687: voltooid

These strings are filtered from a big text file like this:

```
NSData *tmpData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trackTraceFileUrlName] ];
    NSLog(@"%@",trackTraceFileUrlName);
    //convert data to string
    NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tmpData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *piecesArray = [tmpString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSMutableArray *trackTraceContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:piecesArray];
    NSLog(@"%@",trackTraceContent);
    /*Filtering array for referance*/
    NSPredicate *findStringWithReference = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",cRText.text];
    NSArray *trackTraceContentFiltered = [trackTraceContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findStringWithReference];

    /*Filtering array for Collected status*/
    NSPredicate *findStringWithStatusCollected = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'TOMTOM229'"];
    NSArray *filteredArrayOnStatusCollected = [trackTraceContentFiltered filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findStringWithStatusCollected]
    ;
```

The result from filtering the text file will be an Array that contains the filtered objects. This will look like this:

> filteredArrayOnStatusCollected: "51403423 0001051629      1302121101
>   TOMTOM229  Order 51403423-2-477100555: voltooid"

Now i want to sepperate this object so i can put the part where it says 1302121101 into a label. How would i do this?

Comment: Is the object a string?  What data structure are you using to hold this object, what does all of that mean?

Comment: yeah, the object doesn't look like that at all.

Comment: @DanF Yes, its basically a line of text filtered from a big text file.

Comment: is it one object of Array or all of them, in case of all of them this must not be the real representation.

Comment: let me edit my question to make i more clear.

Comment: If that's what you get after reading a big text file, you might reconsider your extraction method before putting the values in an array, and create a multidimensional array instead.

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/05/09/objective-c-lesson-13-key-value-coding/ This would make your application way more clear and the data will be easier to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object is a string, and it is all delimited by spaces, you can get an array of the "tokens" by calling

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Then figuring out how you get specifically the `1302121101` is entirely dependent if you are trying to access a static index of those components, or if you are looking specifically for that text

Comment: Looks a bit more complicated than that; there is an `Order` keyword in there as well as 2 trailing `:` characters to squash.

Comment: See my edited question. Well the string 1302121101 represents a date (yy/mm/dd/hh/mm) so it will be differed every time

Comment: Until he provides a more generic explanation of what it is hes trying to accomplish, this is about the best answer that can be given

Comment: @user1805901 not really, is it the 3rd element you're after?  Is it specifically the string "1302121101", is it something that is formatted as a date as you mention?

Comment: @DanF For this example the array only contains 1 object/string:
51403423 0001051629 1302121101 TOMTOM229 Order 51403423-2-477100555: voltooid

Now i want to cut this object into pices to get the date and present it in a label

Comment: @user1805901  You are trying to get the component "1302121101".  How do you identify that object you're looking for.  You could get it by doing `[filteredArrayContents objectAtIndex:2]`, you could search through the array and find that specific string.  You aren't being specific enough in how you identify THAT component of the object you are trying to access

Comment: @DanF The problem is that the array got only 1 object:
51403423 0001051629 1302121101 TOMTOM229 Order 51403423-2-477100555: voltooid

my question is that i need to separate it so i can do exacly what yo said (object at index)

Comment: Then you need to do exactly as I outlined in my original answer

Comment: @DanF ok let me try this and i come back

Comment: @DanF but how can i converd the array into a string

Comment: The first object in the array should be a string

Answer (score 0):

```
theLable.text = [[theString componentsSeparatedBySring:@" "] objectAtIndex:2];
```

with theLable beeing a `UILable*` and theString being `NSString*`.